# Is it acceptable to use tricks to save programmer when putting data in your code?

Tags: python, coding-style

Example: It's really annoying to type a list of strings in python:

```
["January", "February", "March", "April", ...]
```

I often do something like this to save me having to type quotation marks all over the place:

```
"January February March April May June July August ...".split()
```

Those took the same amount of time, and I got 2x the # of months typed in. Another example:

```
[('a', '9'), ('4', '3'), ('z', 'x')...]
```

instead of:

```
map(tuple, "a9 43 zx".split())
```

which took much less time.

Comment: How much of the time you saved did you use up asking this question?

Comment: I vote for the second example.

Comment: I do this sort of thing from time to time, but when to do it is decided on a case-by-case basis.  Your second example is too much of a stretch for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Code is usually read many times, and it is written only once.
Saving writing time at the expense of readability is not usually a good choice, unless you are doing some throw-away code.

The second version is less explicit, and you need some time to understand what the code is doing. And we are simply talking about variable instantiation, not about algorithms!

Comment: The problem with both examples is that they look weird to other programmers, the long strings do not immediately communicate list of stuff like the arrays do. Therefore they force at least a double take even for these small examples. Very, very bad style.

Comment: Yep, I regularly use and approve (in code reviews and readability reviews) the "some words go here".split() idea, but the second one I'd veto as seriously unreadable.

Comment: I love the first example, detest the second.

Answer (score 19):

A good text editor can make these things a non-issue. For example, I can type the following line in my code:

```
print `"January February March April May June July August September October November December".split()`
```

And then using the key sequence `V:!python<ENTER>` I can run the line through the python interpreter, and the output is the following:

```
['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

I'm using Vim for my example, but I'm sure this is just as easy with Emacs, TextMate, etc.

Comment: Are the backquotes necessary? I find that the same is produced with and without backquotes.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for pointing that out. I was using backquotes just to make sure that the output was a valid python data structure, but it seems that's not necessary for lists.

Comment: +1, not for specific editors but for using the Python interpreter to output a computed data structure representation.

Answer (score 6):

In a reasonably smart editor you could:

1. Select the lines of interest,
2. insert the replacement (`<space>` by "`<space>`" for the 1st ex.),
3. check selected lines checkbox,
4. click replace all,
5. bam.. your done.

Readable *and* easy to type... respect the power of the editor!

Comment: What do you mean readable? It seems like you're just referring to the search and replace feature found in every editor since Notepad...

Comment: Readable refers to the resulting code, i.e. a big string does not communicate "list of stuff" as directly as the built-in list syntax.

Answer (score 5):

In general, I think this is a bad idea. The first example isn't SO bad (it's sort of a substitute for python's lack of qw), but the second is much more difficult to understand. In particular, I think this sort of thing is very unpythonic, and certainly not appropriate when writing Python code, at any rate. Code readability is much more important than saving a little time writing the code. If you really have THAT much data to hardcode, write a script to generate it for you.

Answer (score 3):

How often do you really need to type `["January", "February"... etc]`?

Granted your approach might save you time but why add complexity to your code for no good reason other than you are a bit lazy?

If you really do have to type it that often... Copy-Paste!

Comment: Oops I got beaten to it a few times!

Comment: yes, don't advertise "copy-paste" unless you are in for a beating, it is considered evil (and for the right reasons) ;-)

Comment: I knew that would get me into trouble :P

Answer (score 3):

In production code, do it the right way. In test code, as long as this idiom shows up more than once or twice, I think this is acceptable. If, in test code, this situation shows up once or twice, do it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

> *...I often do something like this to save me having to type quotation marks all over the place...*

I think such a thing should be done only once per program. If you do the same "all over the place" then it doesn't matter which one do you use, you're creating a monster.

Such declaration should be written only ONCE for all the code.

Comment: good pt, but by "all over the place" i meant "all throughout this next line"

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable thing to do for data that you don't expect to change, such as months or days of the weeks. It's also reasonable to do this while mocking up or stubbing out interactions with files or databases, because it isolates your code for testing. However, this isn't a good long-term solution for production code, nor does it really save you much time. Anything big enough to allow big time-savings is big enough to require storing data someplace else, like a separate file o a database.

Answer (score 1):

I all but swear by [Steve McConnell's *Code Complete*](http://www.powells.com/partner/24934/biblio/9780735619678): one of the core insights is that bad programmers write code in order to get computers to do something, period, while good programmers write first to write code that people can understand and only second to get the computer to do things.

(Having code that is written without readability as a major concern is like trying to find things in a closet or filing cabinet where people just cram stuff in without any thought to making something you can navigate and find things in.)

I think you could profit a lot from reading *Code Complete*; I know I did.

Answer (score 1):

your quick and clever methods while nice, take more time to read which is not good.  Readability comes first always.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that type of thing should be in the source.

If I were you, I'd have Python evaluate the respective second versions and then paste the results into my source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting statements like

"January February March April May June July August ...".split()

at module global level is fine. This way it is only executed once during import.  I even sometimes use it in non-performance critical functions because of the reduced line noise.

On a sidenote i think that Python Interpreters could be made to execute the "split()" at compile-time which would eradicate the method-call overhead.  Reason being that a string is a builtin literal and Python does not allow to add/override methods on the very base string type so the compiler can know that "".split() can only refer to one specific method.

Answer (score -2):

I would find this acceptable, if a bit lazy, as long as what is being done isn't too performance critical. You could always go back and optimize it if you need more speed.

Comment: I fail to see how something like this could ever be a performance bottleneck. Unless you're doing this to thousands and thousands of lines of text.